# Fedora 20 webserver very slow

Tags: webserver, isp

I got a personal webserver running on my computer. I made sure the port required is open on the firewall and my router, when I access the page via localhost, it's lightning fast. However many other people, including myself from other computers, can barley access it at all. Like, it starts to load, and it'll go for a good 4-5 seconds, then it gives page unreachable and not found errors for 30-40sec.

Speedtest to a server across the country from me showed ping of 15 DL 59mb/s upload 25mb/s pingtest to same area showed 15-17ms (jitter of 3) both with excellent connection quality... I'm not sure what's wrong here.

I can use SSH and SFTP on the same computer perfectly fine, fast and no errors.

I am using Fedora 20 with latest httpd out of yum repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll presume you are running this on your home internet connection.  If so, then remote access to your website will indeed be SLOW.  This is because the uplink (speed going from your computer -> internet) is intentionally throttled by the home internet company to prevent home consumers from running websites and webservers.  Also, home internet providers do not look kindly to home users running websites.

If you want to do this, I suggest going with a co-lo or graduate your connection to a business grade connection.  You'll have to pay a lot more however.

Comment: It is literally a single cgi script page, how could it possibly use more bandwidth than transfering files with SFTP?

Comment: Confirmed - My ISP thorttles http services. Guess it's time to switch to FiOS now.